# I have date time and I want to count but only by date in Oracle, now I have dates but several times

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, casting

I have date time field, lets call it timestamp_1 and I want to display how many rows I have for each date. So I need to have i.e.

```
date         count
2017-11-20   4 
2017-12-01   10
2017-12-10   15
```

using such sql

```
select cast(timestamp_1 as date), count(*)
from table
group by cast(timestamp_1 as date)
order by cast(timestamp_1 as date) desc
```

I got

```
date         count
    2017-11-20   1 
    2017-11-20   1
    2017-11-20   2
    2017-12-01   6
    2017-12-01   4
    2017-12-10   3
    2017-12-10   6
    2017-12-10   6
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to count the number of rows per day? then you can use

TRUNC ( date [, format ] ) in group by 
i.e 
TRUNC(timestamp_1 , 'DD')

Comment: I changed to 
select TRUNC(timestamp_1 , 'DD'), count(*)
from table
group by TRUNC(timestamp_1 , 'DD')
order by TRUNC(timestamp_1 , 'DD') desc
and it works.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be this, I presume:

```
select trunc(timestamp_1), count(*)
from table
group by trunc(timestamp_1)
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use to_char for date column

```
Select to_char(date_column,'DD-MON-YYYY') from some_table
```